# Why is CoffeScript not "reusing" loop variable?

Tags: javascript, loops, coffeescript

I am new to CoffeeScript and very excited about it. I made some basic loops [here](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aconsole.log%20food%20for%20food%20in%20fruits%0A%0Aconsole.log%20food%20for%20food%20in%20vegetables). Now, CoffeeScript is defining a loop variable for ***every*** loop there is as follows:

```
var food, _i, _j, _len, _len1;

for (_i = 0, _len = fruits.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  food = fruits[_i];
  console.log(food);
}

for (_j = 0, _len1 = vegetables.length; _j < _len1; _j++) {
  food = vegetables[_j];
  console.log(food);
}
```

I used to code my loops like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
    console.log(fruits[i]);
}

for(var i = 0; i < vegetables.length; i++) {
    console.log(vegetables[i]);
}
```

`i` was my loop variable for **every** loop (nested loops excluded). Now I learned that you should always declare your variables before defining it. So I changed my coding habits to:

```
var i;
for(i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
    console.log(fruits[i]);
}

for(i = 0; i < vegetables.length; i++) {
    console.log(vegetables[i]);
}
```

As long as I am in the same scope I did not see anything wrong with it, but the compiled CoffeeScript code left me wondering.

Why would CoffeeScript use a different variable for **every** loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having looked at the CoffeeScript source code, here's my (educated) guess:

The CoffeeScript interpreter simply creates a new `for` loop construct for every `for .. in` you write. While constructing output JS, it maintains a table of local variable names and appends to that as necessary.

After all, you could nest these `for .. in` loops, in which case you'd start to need separate loop variables in JS anyway.

It would be necessary to track which variables in a local function scope could be potentially re-used. This is possible, but more complex than it's worth - it simply does not provide any benefit, so CoffeeScript does not do it.

Comment: It can be tricky, if you do it manually, but since CoffeeScript compiles the JS programmatically I thought there was a way of keeping track if one could "reuse" certain variables. Having less variable declarations in your source code is kind of a benefit, isn´t it?

Comment: @Amberlamps No, that's not enough of a benefit to go through the trouble. A variable isn't exactly expensive in JavaScript. Implementing a logic that keeps track of which ones to re-use *is* expensive in comparison. The gain in preventing declaration of a `_j` just because an `_i` already exists is less than negligible.

Comment: I see, but the logic has to keep track only in development mode. Once you are in production mode the compiled JS is used by your customers.

Comment: @Amberlamps Correct. But the point stands that it would provide no benefit (neither performance-wise nor memory-wise) at the client machine, while adding complexity to the interpreter. Why would you want your loop-variables re-used? 99.99% of your users will neither see nor care nor notice.

Comment: I thought that there might be a more convincing argument to it. But I am satisfied with the trade-off explanation of yours :)

Comment: @Amberlamps As indicated, it's only a guess. It's plausible to me, but I still might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The other side of this is, CS can't count on you only using the variable inside of the loop. While it could be dangerous to rely on your iteration variable for use outside the loop, it's possible you will want to. CS reusing it wouldn't give you that chance, if it always used the same variable.

Comment: The variable doesn't exist in the CS source.

Comment: I'm not a CS user, so I'll take your word on that. But there is no way to access an iteration variable? For more complicated loop functions, it seems there would be a way to access this variable. But again, not a CSer, so if that's the strictness that is enforced, I suppose that could be a good thing.

Comment: He posted a link to the source: http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aconsole.log%20food%20for%20food%20in%20fruits%0A%0Aconsole.log%20food%20for%20food%20in%20vegetables

Comment: You can say `for e in array` to get what the OP is doing or [`for e, i in array`](http://coffeescript.org/#try:a%20%3D%20%5B%20'a'%2C%20'b'%2C%20'c'%20%5D%0Afor%20e%2C%20i%20in%20a%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(e%2C%20i)) to get at the index as well.